# How to write in english in an arabic text?

Tags: babel, arabic, abstract, english

I am writing the abstract for my master thesis and I used this code in order to get three abstracts with three different languages - french, english, and arabic - on the same page. The code works perfectly, but there is one problem: I want to write  some english words in the arabic paragraph, but I can't find a way, that works with this code. I am really in a hurry and need a solution for my problem, since I am graduating very soon.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[arabic,francais,english]{babel}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\newcommand{\ab}{\selectlanguage{arabic}}
\newcommand{\fr}{\selectlanguage{french}}
\newcommand{\en}{\selectlanguage{english}}


\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
\fancyhead{} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\cfoot{\thepage} }
\pagenumbering{roman}


\begin{document}
\setcounter{page}{4}

\chapter*{ABSTRACT}
\thispagestyle{empty}
 \ab 

 \section*{ملخص}
 لكتابة العربية هو نظام الكتابة المستخدم في كتابة اللغة العربية، وفي  
 كتابة لغات أخرى في آسيا وإفريقيا كذلك، مثل اللغات الأذرية والسندية 
 والبشتوية والفارسية والبنجابية والكردية واللرية والأردية والمندنكوية 
  وغيرها
 \newline \newline
 \textbf{الكلمات الرئيسية :  }  العربية 
 \fr

 \en

 \section*{Abstract} 

  Anyone who reads Old and Middle English literary texts will be familiar 
  with the mid-brown volumes of the EETS, with the symbol of Alfred's jewel 
embossed on the front cover. Most of the works attributed to King Alfred or 
    to Aelfric, along with some of those by bishop Wulfstan and much 
  anonymous 
  prose and verse from the pre-Conquest period, are to be found within the 
  Society's three series; all of the surviving medieval drama, most of the 
    Middle English romances, much religious and secular prose and verse 
     including the English works of John Gower, Thomas Hoccleve and most of 
     Caxton's prints all find their place in the publications. Without EETS 
      editions, study of medieval English texts would hardly be possible.
  \newline \newline
  \textbf{\textit{Keywords} : }English, text  



   \section*{Résumé}



    La vie en France est très différente de celle au Canada. Ici, il fait 
    toujours chaud. Chaque dimanche, nous allons à la magnifique plage de 
    Biarritz et nous achetons des glaces après avoir nagé dans la mer.

    Les Français sont très sympathiques et accueillants. Nous parlons 
    français lorsque nous sommes dehors, à l'école ou au marché. Cependant, 
    nous continuons de parler canadien à la maison, car mes parents ne 
    veulent pas que je perde ma langue natale.
  \newline \newline
  \textbf{Mots clés : 

   }vie, France.
  \thispagestyle{empty}


  \end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

We need to use `\textLR{text}` to write latin words inside arabic paragraph and `\textAR{كلمة}` for arabic words inside latin paragraph.

**Notes:**

- you need to add `\usepackage[LAE,T1]{fontenc}` to your preamble
- and may be to replace `francais` option of `bable` with `french` option : `\usepackage[arabic,french,english]{babel}`

---

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LAE,T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[arabic,french,english]{babel}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\newcommand{\ab}{\selectlanguage{arabic}}
\newcommand{\fr}{\selectlanguage{french}}
\newcommand{\en}{\selectlanguage{english}}


\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
\fancyhead{} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\cfoot{\thepage}}
\pagenumbering{roman}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{page}{4}

\chapter*{ABSTRACT}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\ab 

\section*{ملخص}
 لكتابة العربية هو نظام الكتابة المستخدم في كتابة اللغة العربية، وفي  
 كتابة لغات أخرى في آسيا وإفريقيا كذلك، مثل اللغات الأذرية والسندية 
\textLR{french or englich words}
 والبشتوية والفارسية والبنجابية والكردية واللرية والأردية والمندنكوية 
  وغيرها
 \newline \newline
 \textbf{الكلمات الرئيسية :  }  العربية 

 \en
 \section*{Abstract} 

  Anyone who reads Old and Middle English literary texts will be familiar 
  with the mid-brown volumes of the EETS, with the symbol of Alfred's jewel 
embossed on the front cover. Most of the works attributed to King Alfred or 
    to Aelfric, along with some of those by bishop Wulfstan and much 
  anonymous 
  \textAR{كلمات عربية}
  prose and verse from the pre-Conquest period, are to be found within the 
  Society's three series; all of the surviving medieval drama, most of the 
    Middle English romances, much religious and secular prose and verse 
     including the English works of John Gower, Thomas Hoccleve and most of 
     Caxton's prints all find their place in the publications. Without EETS 
      editions, study of medieval English texts would hardly be possible.
  \newline \newline
  \textbf{\textit{Keywords}: }English, text  

\fr
   \section*{Résumé}
    La vie en France est très différente de celle au Canada. Ici, il fait 
    toujours chaud. Chaque dimanche, nous allons à la magnifique plage de 
    Biarritz et nous achetons des glaces après avoir nagé dans la mer.

    Les Français sont très sympathiques et accueillants. Nous parlons 
    français lorsque nous sommes dehors, à l'école ou au marché. Cependant, 
    nous continuons de parler canadien à la maison, car mes parents ne 
    veulent pas que je perde ma langue natale.

  \textbf{Mots clés : } vie, France.
  \thispagestyle{empty}


  \end{document}
```

Comment: It works perfectly , thank you very much , you saved my life

Answer (score 0):

I usually simply include the bidi package and then just use the \LR{some latin text} for short pieces of text and \begin{latin} for longer left-to-right text.